# How to convert AVI movie to proper Apple itunes compatible movie?

Tags: ffmpeg, itunes, video-conversion

I am converting an AVI movie to Itunes compatible movie the playback in itunes is garbled.

Hi so I've used the following command with ffmpeg to convert avi to itunes movie:

ffmpeg -i *.avi -c copy -map 0 output.mp4

I also tried:

ffmpeg -i *.avi -c:a aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4

However when I add to itunes library the movie is garbled (later one doesn't even play the movie). What's the right command to convert to mp4 compatible with itunes? Thanks!

Comment: You may have overwritten your input files but ffmpeg will ask you if you want to do that. It does not accept a wildcard as input except for the image demuxer. Use a "for loop" if you want to process several files. If you are using the "`*`" in your question just as a placeholder then please show the complete log from the command.

Comment: 'Smart Converter' - freeware, App Store.